# when to carefully use free() to free up malloc() used memory?

Tags: c, malloc, free

I read from many question here in SO and some other articles regarding free() function in c that frees the memory of unused variables. In my case,  I have the following code block.

```
char *injectStrAt(char *str, char *strToIn, int pos)
{
    char *strC = malloc(strlen(str) + strlen(strToIn) + 1);
    strncpy(strC, str, pos);
    strC[pos] = '\0';
    strcat(strC, strToIn);
    strcat(strC, str + pos);
    return strC;
}
```

The above function I use to inject a string block in to an array. I am using `malloc` to create a new `char*`. In the above case do I need to do `free(strC)` ? advice pls.

Comment: No... you don't use `free()` *inside* `injectStrAt`. You'd need to use it on the array element or whatever holds the address of the string later.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`strC` is the return value of this function, so you don't call `free(strC)` inside the function itself. You need to free it outside the function, the time when this string is not used anymore.

Answer (score 3):

Since your function is returning `strC`, one presumes it must remain valid after the return of this function, thus this function must *not* `free()` that buffer. Once it's freed, the buffer is no longer valid so must not be used.

Your caller is responsible for freeing it in this case.

Answer (score 2):

No you shouldn't free `strC` inside this function because it is the return value of this function. If you do so the statement:

```
return strC;
```

will return some unexpected or garbage value.

```
char* stringA = injectStrAt(str, strToIn, pos);
printf("StringA: %s"); // unexpected value.
```

So when should you free up the memory? Well, you should do it after the value of `strC` is returned from the function `injectStrAt()` to `stringA`, in this particular case. Although generally memory is freed when the string or the variable to which the memory was allocated is no longer required.

```
char* stringA = injectStrAt(str, strToIn, pos);
/... use the string

free(stringA);
```